# Background video won't play once live, only locally

Tags: html, video, background

UPDATE: By locally when I preview my work in the browser. My files are stored in the same folder structure on one of our severs.

UPDATE: Which jpeg reference do you mean? Is this before I try your way of doing it?

UPDATE: this page doesn't load comments or answers so I'll be posting my answers here.

UPDATE: the console does say that the files are missing, but they're not. The site files in their entirety have been uploaded several times. I can provide a screenshot of the folder within the sever if need be.

[image]

I have a background video inserted into my index page but it doesn't play once the site is live. I believe it uses the image fallback. It works fine locally but having problems with absolute urls. I downloaded this from github and the update for this problem is below but the package I downloaded was a newer version anyways. Test link is below the github link.

https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide/archive/0.1.1.zip#

http://bit.ly/1xLpFiu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no_cache" />
<title>M&amp;T Printing Group</title>
<link rel=”author” href=”https://plus.google.com/+MTPrintingGroupKitchener“/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/content.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="QuotesRotator/css/default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="QuotesRotator/css/component.css" />
<script src="QuotesRotator/js/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- github.com/scottjehl/Respond - for IE 8, 7.... -->
<script src="Respond-master/dest/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".subnav").prev().mouseover(function(){
        var sub_menu_shift = parseInt($(this).next().css("height")) + 100;
        $(this).next().css({'position':'relative','bottom':sub_menu_shift});
    });
    });

</script>-->

    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body data-vide-bg="Vide-0.1.2/examples/video/videoMain">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vide-0.1.2/src/jquery.vide.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="Vide-0.1.2/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="Vide-0.1.2/src/jquery.vide.js"></script>
<script>
//    $(document).ready(function () {
//        $(document.body).vide("Vide-0.1.2/examples/video/videoMain"); // Non declarative initialization
//
//        var instance = $(document.body).data("vide"); // Get instance
//        var video = instance.getVideoObject(); // Get video object
//        instance.destroy(); // Destroy instance
//    });
</script>

<div id="indexBG">

<div id="colour-bar-black"></div> <!-- colour-bar-black -->

<div id="nav-wrap">

<ul>
    <li id="link-one" class="orange">
    <a href="printing.html" class="parent-one-link" title="Printing"><span>Printing</span></a>

     <div class="subnav" id="subnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="_printing/digital-printing.html" title="Digital Printing">Digital Printing</a></li>
            <li><a href="_printing/offset-printing.html" title="Offset Printing">Offset Printing</a></li>
            <li><a href="_printing/business-cards&amp;stationery.html" title="Business Cards &amp; Stationery">Business Cards &amp; Stationery</a></li>
            <li><a href="_printing/manuals-reports&amp;catalogues.html" title="Manuals, Reports &amp; Catalogues">Manuals, Reports &amp; Catalogues</a></li>
            <li><a href="_printing/bindery-services.html" title="Bindery Services">Bindery Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="_printing/canada-post.html" title="Canada Post">Canada Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="_printing/graphic-design-typesetting.html" title="Graphic Design &amp; Typesetting">Graphic Design &amp; Typesetting</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.subnav -->

    </li>

    <li class="red"><a href="promotional-products.html" title="Promotional Products"><span class="doubleLine">Promotional Products</span></a>

    <div class="subnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/awards-mounting.html" title="Awards &amp; Mounting">Awards &amp; Mounting</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/binders.html" title="Binders">Binders</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/clothing-apparel.html" title="Clothing &amp; Apparel">Clothing &amp; Apparel</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/bags.html" title="Bags">Bags</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/drinkware.html" title="Drinkware">Drinkware</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/lanyards.html" title="Lanyards">Lanyards</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/magnets.html" title="Magnets">Magnets</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/pens-writing-instruments.html" title="Pens &amp; Writing Instruments">Pens &amp; Writing Instruments</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/presentation-folders.html" title="Presentation Folders">Presentation Folders</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/usb.html" title="USB Flash Drives">USB Flash Drives</a></li>
            <li><a href="_promotional-products/umbrellas.html" title="Umbrellas">Umbrellas</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.subnav -->

    </li>

    <li class="pink"><a href="banners-signage.html" title="Banners &amp; Signage"><span class="doubleLine">Banners &amp; Signage</span></a>

    <div class="subnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="_banners-signage/drafting-cad-services.html" title="Drafting &amp; CAD services">Drafting &amp; CAD services</a></li>
            <li><a href="_banners-signage/coroplast&amp;foamcore.html" title="Coroplast &amp; FoamCore">Coroplast &amp; FoamCore</a></li>
            <li><a href="_banners-signage/retractable-banners.html" title="Retractable Banners">Retractable Banners</a></li>
            <li><a href="_banners-signage/posters&amp;banners.html" title="Posters &amp; Banners">Posters &amp; Banners</a></li>
            <li><a href="_banners-signage/wraps&amp;pvc.html" title="Wraps &amp; PVC">Wraps &amp; PVC</a></li>
            <li><a href="_banners-signage/displays&amp;canvas.html" title="Displays &amp; Canvas">Displays &amp; Canvas</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.subnav -->

    </li>

    <li class="purple"><a href="pool.html" title="POOL"><span>POOL</span></a></li>

    <li class="blue"><a href="http://www.volumesdirect.com/" title="Volumes"><span>Volumes</span></a></li>

    <li class="green"><a href="contact.html" title="Contact"><span>Contact</span></a>

    <div class="subnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="locations.html" title="Locations">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="media.html" title="Media">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://digitalink2.mtprint.com/exchweb/bin/auth/owalogon.asp?url=https://digitalink2.mtprint.com/exchange&reason=0&replaceCurrent=1" title="Digital Link">Digital Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="ftp://ftp.mtprint.com/" title="FTP site">FTP site</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://secure.mtprint.com/pool/CustSignIn.aspx" title="Client Login">Client Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="mtprint/QuoteForm.aspx" title="Estimate Request">Estimate Request</a></li>
            <li><a href="submit/submit_file.aspx" title="Submit A File">Submit A File</a></li>
            <li><a href="_contact/recognition.html" title="Recognition">Recognition</a></li>
            <li><a href="_contact/graphics-factory.html" title="Graphics Factory">Graphics Factory</a></li>
            <li><a href="_contact/careers.html" title="Careers">Careers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.subnav -->

    </li>

    <li class="yellow-facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mtprint/" title="Facebook"><span></span></a></li>

</ul>

</div> <!-- nav-wrap -->

<div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-main.png" alt="M&amp;T Printing Group" title="M&amp;T Printing Group" /></a></div> <!-- logo -->

<!-- used for mobile -->

<div id="logo-mobile"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/M&T-Printing-Group-Logo-moble.jpg" alt="M&amp;T Printing Group" title="M&amp;T Printing Group" /></a></div> <!-- logo-mobile -->

<h1>&ldquo;Your Partners In Print&rdquo;</h1>

<div id="footer">        

<ul class="footer-left">
    <li><a href="index.html">M&amp;T Printing Group</a> - &copy; 2014</li>
</ul>

<ul class="footer-right">
 <li><a href="https://secure.mtprint.com/pool/CustSignIn.aspx" title="Client Login">Client Login</a></li>
 <li><a href="locations.html" title="Locations">Locations</a></li>
 <li><a href="pool.html" title="Pool">Pool</a></li>
</ul>

</div> <!-- footer -->   

</div> <!-- indexBG -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please check the console it says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

I would just do something like this, using jquery. You can have the videoURL go to whichever you like and it will load right up. I have done this in the past for several websites and it works wonderfully. The below is just html and JQUERY. Your issue seems to me seems to be were you have the video stored. You said it works fine "locally" Well where are you hosting your webpage? Your video should be stored in the same venue.

```
<section class="content-section video-section">
   <div class="pattern-overlay">
    <a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sd4bqmP_460',containment:'', quality:'large', autoPlay:true, mute:true, opacity:1}">bg</a>
    </div>
</section>


$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".player").mb_YTPlayer();

});
```

I see the edit you added. Remove the jpeg or reference the mp4 file.

--Sorry for editing your comment but it's the only way I can respond.Which jpeg reference do you mean?

Comment: $(document.body).vide("Vide-0.1.2/examples/video/videoMain.mp4")